# Volts and frequency worldwide

Tags: power, voltage, frequency, safety

If an electrical certification tag reads 220-240V 50/60 Hz can the device be used on both 220V 50 Hz and 240V 60 Hz?

Comment: Since the edit changes the nature of the previously answered question, it should be posted as a new question.

Answer (score 7):

In a word, yes, since any voltage-frequency combination stated is permitted.

Comment: Watch out! You can't use the device worldwide. Japan for example uses "only" 100V (see this table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mains_electricity_by_country#Table_of_mains_voltages_and_frequencies)

Comment: Why is that relevant?

Comment: The topic is "Volts and frequency worldwide"

Comment: The topic is: "Volts and frequency worldwide", but the question is: "If an electrical certification tag reads 220-240V 50/60 Hz can the device be used on both 220V 50 Hz and 240V 60 Hz?", which makes your warning irrelevant.